# Flutter Stripe payment intent without secret-key

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments, flutter-stripe

I'm trying to add Stripe payment intent in flutter but the issue is in the new library **flutter_stripe: ^7.0.0** requires a secret key but the secret key is handled in the backend API(server).

I did it earlier with stripe_payment but now the library stopped working.
So if you guys have any solution let me know.
Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to use the Stripe secret key from the client, that is a really bad idea. If a hacker gets the key, which is not very difficult, they can do serious damage to your finances. You have to use the secret key from the server only. You call a server function from the client, the server function has the key. Don't try and do it any other way.

Comment: I recommend looking at this doc as well: https://docs.page/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/sheet#2-add-an-enpoint-server-side

It goes over the Flutter SDK's recommended way of setting up card payments with PaymentSheet. As Graham mentioned, your secret key should be used exclusively by your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final paymentIntent = await Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(
      clientSecret,
      const PaymentMethodParams.card(
        paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(),
      ));
  // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text('Success!: The payment was confirmed successfully!')));
  NavigationHelper.pushReplacement(context, BottomNavBody(data: widget.data,));
```

This is the code for doing payment intent while stripe secret key is handled by server side.